# Continious icon rotation

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is there a way to continuously rotate an icon from the CalciteWebCoreIcons?

I have a layer with the single icon on it, that shows up correctly.

```
    view.graphics.add({
      id: "centers",
      symbol: {
        type: "text",
        color: getRandomColor(),
        text: "\ue613",
        angle: 180,
        font: {
          size: 30,
          family: "CalciteWebCoreIcons"
        }
      },
      geometry: {
        type: "point",
        latitude: parseFloat(_lat),
        longitude: parseFloat(_lon)
      },
      popupTemplate: {
        title: "",
        content: ""
      }
    });
```

Basically, i would like the icon to rotate 360 degrees every 5 seconds, without clearing and reloading the entire layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of December 2018, you would have to clone the graphic, make modifications (angle), add it back and remove the original. See [documentation under "modify graphics"](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/guide/functionality-matrix/index.html#esrilayersgraphicslayer):

> To modify a graphic that is already added to the layer: you need to
>   clone it, make modifications, add it to the layer and remove the
>   original graphic. In-place modification of graphic objects will not
>   trigger display refresh.

[Demo here](https://codepen.io/gavinr/pen/oQKwqq?editors=0010).